# how to hide toggle sidebar when I launch my own website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a site with toggle sidebar for my menu, but the button inside of the toggle sidebar every time will show up when I load the site without user's clicking on the toggle sidebar button. Please guide me to the way to fixes this, thank you.

[image: This is when I load the site side menu will automatic popout without clicking on the toggle sidebar]
[image: This is what I want when I load my site]

Comment: set your toggle div style="display: none;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple example that uses html, css, and 5 lines of javascript:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const button = document.querySelector('button');

  button.addEventListener('click', _ => {
    document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle('collapsed');
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#sidebar, #content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow:auto;
  float:left;
  transition: width .35s;
}

#sidebar {
  background:white;
  width: 30%;
  box-shadow: 2px 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

#sidebar.collapsed {
  width: 0;
}

#sidebar.collapsed + #content {
  width: 100%;
}

#content {
  background:gray;
  width: 70%;
}

button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  background: black;
  margin: 20px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

h3 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar" class="collapsed">
  
</div>
<div id="content">
  <button title="Toggle sidebar"></button>
  <h3>Some content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried out this one, the script tag unable to run if it was in the head tag, only able to run when I put script tag after the button tag

Comment: The document must be ready by the time the 'click' listener is added to it. So you can either add it after the button tag like you mentioned or put it inside the window.DomContentLoaded callback: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event()